# JS: Getting the output but not in correct format while calling two functions person_A( ) and Person_B( ) based on 3 steps using setTimeout( )

Tags: javascript, settimeout, arrow-functions

```js
/* Let's assume we have two functions person_A() and person_B().
step1: executing/calling person_A() first and then person_B().
step2: executing/calling person_B() first and then person_A() with 3 seconds delay.
step3: executinng/calling person_A() first and then person_B with 3 seconds delay.*/

console.log("\n-----------> STEP 1 <----------------\n");
let person_A=()=>{
  console.log(" Hi Am person_A() ");
}

let person_B=()=>{
  console.log(" Hi Am person_B() ");
}

person_A();
person_B();

console.log("\n-----------> STEP 2 <----------------\n");

/* here am just adding setTimeout() to delay person_A() for 3 seconds for the above STEP-1 code  */

 

   person_A=()=>{
   setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(" Hi Am person_A() ");
    },3000)
}

   person_B=()=>{
  
  console.log(" Hi Am person_B() ");
}

person_A();
person_B();


console.log("\n-----------> STEP 3 <----------------\n");
/* moving/paste the person_B() in person_A() as shown in STEP 3, which means once the person_A() is executed then it will call the person_B() eventhough their is a 3 seconds delay. */
person_A=()=>{
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(" Hi Am person_A() ");
      person_B();
    },3000)
}

 person_B=()=>{
  console.log(" Hi Am person_B() ");
}

person_A();
// person_B();
```

[**Correct Output :**

### Step-1 :

person_A( )
person_B( )

### Step-2 :

person_B( )
person_A( )

### Step-3 :

person_A( )
person_B( )  ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEfFq.png)

[**Incorrect Output :**

### Step-1 :

person_A( )
person_B( )

### Step-2 :

person_B( )

### Step-3 :

person_A( )
person_A( )
person_B( ) ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toNMw.png)

Comment: Am newbie to Javascript kindly helpme out to get the expected ouput for reference purpose kindly checkout the Images as well.

Comment: It's working as expected.  In the "incorrect output" the first person A in step 3 is the expected completion of step 2.  You can see for yourself by changing the log messages to label which experiment that the log is part of.

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason is because asynchronous codes is scheduled to execute later. All synchronous codes executes in order.

You need to make sure that step 2 completes before step 3 starts.
Here is a option, but it is not the only one.

```
console.log("\n-----------> STEP 2 <----------------\n");

/* here am just adding setTimeout() to delay person_A() for 3 seconds for the above STEP-1 code  */


person_A = () => {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(" Hi Am person_A() ");
        step3();
    }, 3000)
}

person_B = () => {

    console.log(" Hi Am person_B() ");
}

person_A();
person_B();


function step3() {
    
    console.log("\n-----------> STEP 3 <----------------\n");
    /* moving/paste the person_B() in person_A() as shown in STEP 3, which means once the person_A() is executed then it will call the person_B() eventhough their is a 3 seconds delay. */

    person_A = () => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(" Hi Am person_A() ");
            person_B();
        }, 3000)
    }

    person_B = () => {
        console.log(" Hi Am person_B() ");
    }

    person_A();
    person_B();
}
```

Comment: Haa.. Cool...Can we make this code run synchronously by using clearTimeout( ) or any other method. If yes kindly help me out..

Comment: If I try to execute some other code which is just right below the end of the step3 code The some other code output getting displayed first and then lastly step3 gets displayed.

Comment: As you mentioned the code running Asyncronously and we need to make it in sync is thier any way please help me...

Comment: Once you set a timer, that code will not execute until the timer expires. Clear timeout, will remove the timer, so the code that was part of  it, will not execute. If you want the code to run synchronously, remove the timers.